# Localstack/localstack startup trouble

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, makefile, docker-compose, localstack

I am using MACOSX to run and test some of my services, am also using localstack (https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to mimic s3, sqs and sns but this does not seem to be working right.

Ive already increased the compute power and memory for docker to max.

```
C-LM-0792:Desktop UserName$ git clone git@github.com:localstack/localstack.git
Cloning into 'localstack'...
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 15, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 6741 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 6726
Receiving objects: 100% (6741/6741), 2.23 MiB | 1.92 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4397/4397), done.
C-LM-0792:Desktop UserName$ cd localstack/
C-LM-0792:localstack UserName$ make infra
(. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start)
/bin/sh: .venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
make: *** [infra] Error 1
C-LM-0792:localstack UserName$ make web
(. .venv/bin/activate; bin/localstack web)
/bin/sh: .venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
make: *** [web] Error 1
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend starting via `docker-compose` rather than building from source unless you have a good reason to. https://github.com/localstack/localstack#running-in-docker. Using this approach you don't need to clone/build/start localstack yourself because the localstack images are published in docker hub

Comment: @Brian Yes, I tried using `docker-compose` and it works well, the container builds and services are running. Thanks

Comment: You can also install directly from Commandeer  https://getcommandeer.com/blog/install-localstack . Which also gives you a UI for viewing your localstack data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following docker-compose file as pointed by @brian in the comment:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4599:4567-4599"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Commandeer](https://getcommandeer.com), you can view your LocalStack instance.  Under the hood it uses the above docker instance, but you can then start and stop services from the GUI.  It also prints out the contents of the terminal in the terminal tab.  I would go the docker route for it, because it is now their recommended way of doing it.

[image]

Comment: isn't comandeer a paid tool? can you suggest any opesource tool for  viewing localstack instances?

Comment: @OmPS - if you want to just view the containers, you could use Docker Desktop or Portainer.